# Jenkinsfile manual input if not supplied by rest api

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

USE CASE: I'm writing a job in jenkins that can be triggered either inside the Jenkins UI, or via the REST API. It has 5 variables, including a multi-choice (yet to be implemented).

PROBLEM: I'm stuggling to get anything to work. The nearest guide I've found is [this one from medium](https://medium.com/disney-streaming/jenkins-pipeline-with-dynamic-user-input-9f340fb8d9e2)

My code is currently looking something like below.

```
pipeline{
  agent any

  environment{
    foo = ""
    bar = ""
    orange = ""
    apple = ""

    fooBar = "" // "$foo.$bar"

    inputSupplied = false
  }

  stages{
    stage("Set variables") {
      stages{
        stage("Request user input") {
          when{ expression { env.inputSupplied = false}}
          steps{
            echo "Inputs supplied via Jenkins User Input"
            parameters{
              string(name:"FOO", defaultValue:"7", description: "Foo version")
              string(name:"BAR", defaultValue:"22", description: "Bar version")
              string(name:"ORANGE", defaultValue:"0", description: "Orange version")
              string(name:"APPLE", defaultValue:"", description: "Apple version")
            }
          }
        }
        stage("Set variables from external input") {
          when {expression { env.inputSupplied = true}}
          steps{
            echo "Inputs supplied via API"
          }
        }
        stage("Validation") {
          steps{
            echo "Starting validation"
          }
        }

      }
    }

    stage ("Onwards"){...}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameter directive are allowed only in pipeline scope not to any scope, please [check this link](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters). You can move the parameter block outside of blocks to make it work. Also I'm not sure why you want nested stages blocks in your script, stages directive is allowed only once inside the pipeline scope, please refer [this link](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#stages) hope below will work for your requirement.

```
 pipeline{
  agent any

  environment{
    foo = ""
    bar = ""
    orange = ""
    apple = ""

    fooBar = "" // "$foo.$bar"

    inputSupplied = false
  }
  parameters{
    string(name:"FOO", defaultValue:"7", description: "Foo version")
    string(name:"BAR", defaultValue:"22", description: "Bar version")
    string(name:"ORANGE", defaultValue:"0", description: "Orange version")
    string(name:"APPLE", defaultValue:"", description: "Apple version")
  }

  stages{
    stage("Set variables") {
        steps{
            echo "Setting a Variables"
        }
    }
    stage("Request user input") {
        when{ expression { env.inputSupplied == 'false' }}
        steps{
            echo "Inputs supplied via Jenkins User Input"
        }
    }
    stage("Set variables from external input") {
        when {expression { env.inputSupplied == 'true'}}
        steps{
            echo "Inputs supplied via API"
        }
    }
    stage("Validation") {
        steps{
            echo "Starting validation"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Mulitple Nested stages works and it is when you have to do some stuffs like build and deploy for same stage and but you want  have separate  stage view and should be under same stage

Comment: I'm using sequential stages to help break up the script. see [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#sequential-stages) on the same page you linked.

Comment: @AlistairHardy have you tried as I answerd above? because I am using the same

Answer (score 0):

Define global boolean and try like this.

```
inputSupplied = false

pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage("Set variables from external input") {
    when {
      expression { 
        return !inputSupplied 
      }
    }
    steps{
        echo "Inputs supplied via API"
     }
    }
   }
  }
```

and later if you want to chnage the value of the boolean just define again using `inputSupplied = true` in stpes block where you want to change when something happens condition like this so that it will get overide the default value